# Tomcat7 Service Cannot Start on Windows 7 Even When It Is Set to Log In as Administrator

Tags: windows-7, tomcat

I cannot automatically start the Tomcat7 service at startup on my Windows 7 laptop. On restarting Windows, I get the message "Access is Denied. Unable to Open the Service Tomcat7" *even though* I have the service set to log in as Administrator.

I've also set the Tomcat directory (which I located outside of the Program Files directories) and all its subdirectories to "Full Control" for all users (which should be overkill). Yet I *can* start it manually using the "Run as Administrator" context menu item.

If *that* works, why won't setting it to run as Administrator as a service work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting the very same error and I managed to sort it out. 
Though in my case, even though the same error occurred on every start of the machine, the service was running, as I was able to use my app. But I seriously wanted to get rid of this problem so the client will not be forced to see this annoying error.

The way I did it was set up the tomcat7w.exe to always start as an administrator.
Exactly you do it in the following way: right click on the tomcat7w.exe which is in the 'bin' folder of the tomcat installation, select 'Properties', then in 'Compatibility' tab under 'Privilege Level' select the 'Run this program as an administrator'.

I have put my answer for completeness as I think this might be the only way for Win 7 Home users, as in this version there is simply no option to set Local Policies which is required in the answer provided by @ta.speot.is  (BTW +1)

Answer (score 2):

> If that works, why won't setting it to run as Administrator as a service work?

Presumably Administrator doesn't have *[Log on as a service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424(WS.10).aspx)* granted to it.

Comment: Since I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium (I'm trying to run Tomcat so i can run the Endeavour Mgmt application), the "Users and Groups" applet is not present. The solution I found was to download the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit (thanks to this  [blog post](http://toblogornottoblog.co.uk/blog/misc-it/1/how-to-grant--log-on-as-batch-job--in-windows-7-home-premium.php?blog=159&page=1&order=d&mode=h)) and use the _ntrights.exe_ utility to set the correct permissions ([ntrights.exe instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279664)).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Blomkvist's answer, you can use **msconfig.exe** to **disable the startup** of "Commons Daemon Service Manager" (Tomcat7w.exe). It won't run properly anyway during startup when you have "Run As Administrator" enabled.

*Some Background regarding the default installation of Tomcat7 with Service:*
`Tomcat7w.exe` is Apache's "Commons Daemon Service Manager". 
By default, it is configured to run during startup, under the current user. It tries to connect to the `Tomcat7.exe` Service, which by default runs as user "SYSTEM". The problem is, the current user has not enough privileges to manipulate services or processes of user SYSTEM.

You may disable the "Commons Daemon Service Manager". It only provides convenience remote control of the service process. You can achieve all the same by using the Services administrative tool, or the command line `net` or `sc` command. Put these in a batch file and change it's property to Run As Administrator (They must be run with Administrator privileges as well.)

```
net stop "Tomcat7"
net start "Tomcat7"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with the tray icon, then just run `Monitor Tomcat` under the **Start Menu**. It will appear as it does after the installation. Damn, it feels good starting/stopping the service that way

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the tomcat7w.exe (found at %CATALINA_HOME%\bin). Click on the Properties menu item and then select the Compatibility tab. Check the Run this program as an administrator checkbox under the Privilege Level section. Click the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

Download the installer .exe file for Tomcat7 in-order to install and run the Tomcat7(32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer (pgp, md5, sha1)).

Do not download the Zip file of Tomcat7